# Should I have more trees than dimensions for the Isolation Forest?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset which has 200 dimensions after pre-processing. I read multiple times that 100 is the recommended number of trees for the Isolation Forest. Since each tree chooses **one** feature randomly, all the features of my dataset wouldn't be used by the Isolation Forest which means that the not used dimension could contain anomalies which would stay undetected.

I am not sure if I understand something wrong, but shouldn't be the number of trees higher than number of dimensions, so that all the features can be used and inspected by the forest?

Comment: Why do you think that one tree only uses one feature? At each node in a tree, a feature is selected

Comment: So for each split a new feature is selected randomly ? Then I misunderstood something, my bad!